# Issue with the size of the To field in CRM Email form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We use CRM 2016 SP1 on-premise. We are experiencing an issue with the size of the To field of the built-in email View form whereby the field only displays up to three lines of email addresses and truncates the rest.

I know that I can click the list and scroll it in the Edit form, but this is not an option in the View form.

Is there any way to get the To field to expand/scroll in the View form?

Answer (score 0):

This is product limitation to show maximum 3 rows. But you should see scroll bar to look at all other recipients.

Another option is click on Lens icon & inline Lookup window will open, if you scroll all the way down - you can see `Look up More Records`, click it. This will open Lookup popup where 5 lines of recipients will show, where you can add/remove in bulk.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

It seems your issue is with Closed activities, this form may be limited for customizations. Try Print (Ctrl+P) to see whether all the recipients are showing.

Comment: Hi Arun. Thanks for your reply. It is true that I can click on the email list to see the scroll bar. But what I meant was (and I should have explained it in my question) I cannot see the whole list or be able to scroll it when opening an existing email in the View form. To be able to scroll the list, I am having to click the Reply All button, go to the edit page and scroll it then. Is there any way to modify the To field in the View form?

Comment: @seemorgh this is why you should add screenshot. View mean grid ?

Comment: You mean received or sent email record? I don’t think so you can do that. Try print option if it works for you

Comment: Sorry Arun, I did not have a test email in the system to add a screenshot of. But does it matter if it is sent or received? I am talking about email list you go to when you go to Main Menu->Activities and select Emails where I can open existing emails in what appears to be a View only form.

Comment: Yeah right sent/received - they are closed activities (read only). Reply/Reply all/new Email/ draft are open activities (editable).

Comment: So I take it it's not possible to modify the To field in the View form.